# how can I invoke this PHP script using curl? (from bash command line)

Tags: php, bash, curl

I have written a script in PHP whose purpose is simply to query a DB and then send an email with the results.

I can invoke the script with a browser by simply requesting the URL with the query string, e.g. typing into the address bar

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php?model=manage&view=main
```

This invokes the script and everything works fine. 
note: some HTML is produced by the script - which is caused by the fact my script is hooking into a larger application.

When I try to invoke the script from the bash command line with:

```
curl http://localhost/myapp/index.php?model=manage&view=main
```

curl displays the HTML that is generated by the script, but the curl process doesnt complete - I have to `ctrl + c` out of the curl process and also script is not processed properly and the email is not sent

apache access log output

it seems Apache is truncating the 2nd variable in the query string

127.0.0.1 - - [08/Apr/2015:01:28:47 +1200] "GET /myapp/index.php?model=manage HTTP/1.1" 200 23549 "-" "curl/7.35.0"

Comment: You can redirect the output of the curl by: `curl http://localhost/myapp/index.php?model=manage&view=main 2> /dev/null`

Comment: thanks, but that still hasn't fixed the issue.

Comment: You can execute the script on the same server by using PHP CLI: `php index.php manage main` but you have to replace the `$_GET['model']` -> `$argv[1]`, and `$_GET['view']` -> `$argv[2]` on the code.

Comment: good idea, but unable to change the `$_GET` variables because the larger application that performs initialisation uses them. Also I suspect the `php.ini` differences between `mod-apache` and `php-cli` might cause problems in production

Comment: Try to use `wget` instead of `curl` (with redirecting the output to /dev/null)

Comment: close: apache log file shows apache is receiving a `GET` request for index.php?model=manage**amp**view=main   (Ive bolded the malformed part of the URL)

Comment: Use double quotes to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `&` character e.g by putting the URL in double quotes as in:

```
curl "http://localhost/myapp/index.php?model=manage&view=main"
```

that will preserve the second query parameter.

Comment: upvote, thanks the log is definitely showing the correct URL now. the script is not being executed still though

Comment: Is output of the script in the browser different from console one?
Is resulted html page contained any AJAX request to another scripts?

Comment: @max HTML Output between browser and console is the same. i.e. the `<head>` section (and all the linked resources - stylesheets etc ) is output.  The main difference I can tell is the browser then reads the `<head>` and makes subsequent  requests for the linked resources - stylesheets, js etc - (which all show up in access.log). using curl there is only the one request hitting apache

Comment: check the headers that the browser sends and copy those over in your cURL command

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to request the URL in chrome with dev tools open.
I watched for the request in the network tab, then right-clicked the request and selected the "save as curl option".

I then pasted the (long) curl command into the terminal - which contained the options and parameters necessary to get the curl request to work.